# Python :: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'interfaces'

Tags: python

I downloaded a python project from [github](https://github.com/dggreenbaum/debinterface):

to work with interface file of ubuntu.
the problem is when I try to use the module as the Readme said I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ss.py", line 7, in <module>
    adapters = debinterface.interfaces()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'interfaces'
```

my `ss.py` script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import debinterface
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/ed/Downloads/netpy/")
sys.path.append("/home/ed/Downloads/netpy/debinterface/")
adapters = debinterface.interfaces()
```

I run this script within `"/home/ed/Downloads/netpy/"` that consists of `"debinterface"`. I have to say that I tried that script without `"sys.path.append"` but nothing changed, even I changed the module name `"debinterface"` to `"debeh"` but again nothing changed too.

what is my problem?

Comment: Do you have a `debinterface.py` file where you are currently trying to run this?

Comment: Have you tried the over-route method of putting all of them in a package and then trying `from package import *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the documentation or the package code to me. You can use

```
from debinterface.interfaces import interfaces
```

and then refer to your the `interface` class with

```
adapters = interfaces()
```

or edit `debinterface/__init__.py` to do the import of `interface` module for you when you import the `debinterface` package. Add the line

```
from interfaces import interfaces
```

to the `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working doing the following:

1. Downloaded the zip from github;
2. Extracted the zip and renamed it to debinterfaces;
3. Created a python module in the same directory that debinterfaces folder is;
4. Changed the import statement:

   ```
   from debinterface.interfaces import interfaces
   ```
5. And finally, called interfaces:

   ```
   adapters = interfaces()
   ```